# Images of Allah in prayer

Tags: salat, shirk, waswasa

I was recently given a video where a sheikh says that whoever visualizes an image while reciting IYYAKA NA'BUDU WA IYYYAKA NASTAEEN, then he worships that image that he visualized in his head. I am very much tormented because of this. All kinds of images appear in my mind even when I am just washing dishes. I don't believe in them, and I say that Allah is not like anyone or anything. I am afraid to perform prayer because I am afraid of committing shirk because of these thoughts. What should I do in this situation?

Comment: These thoughts are from the devil, the prophet(saw) has told us what to do in this situation, which is to seek refuge in allah(istiadah)

Answer (score 0):

Salaamu alaikum, There is no imagine you can imagine that is like Allah. Allah does not hold us accountable for our thoughts that we do not put into action, so if you do not draw or begin to create idols from these images that you see, you are not commiting shirk. Please return to your prayers regardless of what you imagine.

Abu Hurayrah  may  Allaah  be  pleased  with  him narrated that the Prophet  sallallaahu  `alayhi  wa  sallam ( may  Allaah exalt his mention ) said: “Allah has forgiven my nation for the whispers that they have unless they speak about it or act according to it.”

Allahu A'lam

Answer (score -1):

Asalamualaikum I searched your question up on Youtube and Sheikh Assim al hakeem said that you're not allowed to speaxk about
these  thoughts/images and you're not allowed to act upon them. HEre is the viedeo if you wan't to see it https://youtu.be/Hh8CHKuE9WE?si=4RY7tcEs02m16TVl